# How to Change TextBox (dijit/form/TextBox) Focus color

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.form

I tried to create TextBoxEx which extends dijit/form/TextBox . TextBoxEx override _onFocus (see code below) but TextBox doesn't change background color. It always be tranparent. What's my fault?

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare", // declare
    "dijit/form/TextBox",
    "dojo/on",
    "dojo/_base/event",
    "dojo/dom-style"
], function(declare, TextBox, on, event, domStyle) {

    var widget = declare("common.TextBoxEx", [TextBox], {

        inputLanguage : '',
        focusColor : '#F5EC9B',
        selectOnClick : true,
        _onFocus: function(e){
            try{
                if(this.disabled || this.readOnly){ return; }
                this.inherited(arguments);
                this._updatePlaceHolder();
                var evt = document.createEvent("Events");
                if(this.inputLanguage == 'en'){
                    evt.initEvent   ('switchToEng', true, false);
                    window.dispatchEvent(evt);
                }
                else if(this.inputLanguage == 'th'){
                    evt.initEvent('switchToThai', true, false);
                    window.dispatchEvent(evt);
                }

                var dom = this.focusNode;
                var focusColor = this.focusColor;

                setTimeout(function() {
                    dom.select();
                    domStyle.set(dom, 'background-color', focusColor);

                }, 200);
            }
            catch(e){
                console.log(e)
            }
        },

    });

    return widget;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually don't need to set the background color like this. Just use css to do this:

```
.myTextBoxClass.dijitTextBox.dijitFocused .dijitInputInner {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

Just change `.myTextBoxClass` to whatever class you give your textbox.

Answer (score 0):

override you default theme CSS with your own style using !important. Such type of work can be done using CSS only.